# How to assign an array inside a while loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment, assign

I'm trying to read values from a .txt file, line by line, then store it inside of an array so that I can use those values later in my program.
The problem is that when I print my array inside of the loop, it prints just fine but when I try to print it outside of loop it doesn't print anything.

## txt file:

> I/P voltage : 212.0
>   I/P fault voltage : 212.0
>   O/P voltage :
>   212.0
>   O/P current : 000
>   I/P frequency : 50.0
>   Battery voltage : 13.7
>   Temperature : 28.0
>   UPS Status : 00001001

## my code:

array name is `$UPS_respond`

```
<?php
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Read value from file
# -----------------------------------------------------

    $i      = 0 ;
    $file   = fopen("/usr/local/bin/UpsResult.txt","r"); //i open my file to read it
    $dot    = 0;

    while( !feof( $file ) ) {
        $y      = fgets($file);
        $dot    = strpos($y,':')+1; 
        $x      = substr($y, $dot);
        $UPS_respond = array($i => $x);
        echo "inside of Loop => ".'$UPS_respond['.$i.'] :'.$UPS_respond[$i]."<br>"; 
        $i++;
    }
    fclose( $file );
    echo "Ouside of Loop => ".$UPS_respond[$i]."<br>";
?>
```

## result:

```
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[0] : 213.5 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[1] : 213.5 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[2] : 213.0 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[3] : 000 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[4] : 50.0 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[5] : 13.7 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[6] : 28.0 
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[7] : 00001001
Ouside of Loop =>
```

Comment: `echo 'Well bugger me, turns out after the loop $i has the following value: ' . $i;`

Comment: If you put `echo $i` you will realize it value is `8` because it got incremented one last time before exiting the loop, and the array has no value assigned to that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Digital_affection

Can you please try following way? Hope it may help you.

```
<?php
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Read value from file
# -----------------------------------------------------

    $i      = 0 ;
    $file   = fopen("/usr/local/bin/UpsResult.txt","r"); //i open my file to read it
    $dot    = 0;
    $result_arr = [];
    while( !feof( $file ) ) {
        $y      = fgets($file);
        $dot    = strpos($y,':')+1; 
        $x      = substr($y, $dot);
        $result_arr[] = $x;
        // $UPS_respond = array($i => $x);
        // echo "inside of Loop => ".'$UPS_respond['.$i.'] :'.$UPS_respond[$i]."<br>"; 
        $i++;
    }
    fclose( $file );
    //echo "<pre>Ouside of Loop => ".$UPS_respond[$i]."<br>";
    echo "<pre>Ouside of Loop => "; print_r( $result_arr );

?>
```

**Result would be like:**

```
Ouside of Loop => Array
(
    [0] =>  212.0

    [1] =>  212.0

    [2] =>  212.0

    [3] =>  000

    [4] =>  50.0

    [5] =>  13.7

    [6] =>  28.0

    [7] =>  00001001
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Ram ! my problem Solved ! not sure what it was tho !

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `$UPS_respond = []` before the `while` loop.
You also have to change

```
$UPS_respond = array($i => $x);
```

to

```
$UPS_respond[$i] = $x;
```

The reason for this is, on each iteration you are replacing the array with a new one. And with the above code, you will add the value to the array, instead of creating a new one each time.

**UPDATE**: I saw another issue. It is with the `echo` at the end. You have all the values in the `array`, but you are only printing the last one, because `$i` is the key to the last array.

You can check with by doing

```
var_dump($UPS_respond);
```

If you tell me, how exactly you want to use the values, I can tell you how to handle it.

Comment: nope , still not working . thanks for answering btw

Comment: it gives some thing like inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[0] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[1] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[2] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[3] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[4] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[5] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[6] :Array
inside of Loop => $UPS_respond[7] :Array
Ouside of Loop =>

Comment: thanks for your help martin . as i suspected the problem was assigning the array and Ram Chander solved it .

Comment: the problem was not what you explained . the problem was only the way i assigned the array .

Comment: you right . i sorry . im a php noob so i didn't understand you perfectly !!! my bad

Comment: @Digital_affection Why did you swap it again? Is there something unclear or?

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

You can make things easier with the following approach. Use `file()` and `explode()` PHP functions to read the content of your file and to parse the content of each line.

```
<?php
// Read file
$UPS_respond = file('UpsResult.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Output
foreach ($UPS_respond as $line) {
    $a = explode(':', $line);
    echo "Item info: ".$a[0]." : ".$a[1]."<br>"; 
};
?>
```

Output:

```
Item info: I/P voltage : 212.0
Item info: I/P fault voltage : 212.0
Item info: O/P voltage : 212.0
Item info: O/P current : 000
Item info: I/P frequency : 50.0
Item info: Battery voltage : 13.7
Item info: Temperature : 28.0
Item info: UPS Status : 00001001
```

**Update:**

If you want to get only part of your lines, use the next approach. The reason for the error in your script is that you need to add an item in the `$UPS_respond` array with `$UPS_respond[] = ...;`.

```
<?php
// Read file
$file = file('UpsResult.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Output
$UPS_respond = array();
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $a = explode(':', $line);
    $UPS_respond[] = $a[1];
};
var_dump($UPS_respond);
// ?>
```

Comment: that looks good but i just want to read numbers in each line . for example in line 1 i need 212.0 only

Comment: @Digital_affection The reason for your error is that you need to use `$UPS_respond[] = ...;` to add an item in an array.